# How to save clipped path only in Android

Tags: android

This is what I have:

```
Bitmap result = Bitmap.create(600, 600, Config.ARG_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.clipPath(path) // custom path is a rotated rectangle that has an offset x and y within the 600x600 rectangle
canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
canvas.save();
```

When I check the result bitmap, I only see the clip path which is I want, but I want the result image to be the same size as the clip path and not still 600x600.

Thanks

Comment: crop it then by a Path's Bounds

Comment: So what you mean is that I could do Bitmap.createBitmap(src, left, top, width, height, matrix, true)? the matrix would contain the angle at which the rectangle is rotated?

Comment: angle?  what angle?  no,  use drawBitmap ( Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)

Comment: That doesn't work, it only scales my whole image to the bounds it doesn't crop the original to the custom path I've clipped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as i said in the comment above, you can use `drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)` to crop your `Bitmap result` to the cropped one or you can do it directly:

```
// get the Bitmap
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

// setup sample Path
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(10, 10);
path.lineTo(30, 10);
path.lineTo(30, 20);
path.close();

RectF bounds = new RectF();
path.computeBounds(bounds, true);
Rect pathBounds = new Rect();
bounds.roundOut(pathBounds);

Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pathBounds.width(), pathBounds.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Shader shader = new BitmapShader(b, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Canvas c = new Canvas(outBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setShader(shader);
c.translate(-pathBounds.left, -pathBounds.top);
c.drawPath(path, paint);
```